# Storing data to google cloud storage using gae for java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

i am trying to store data from the app engine app to google cloud storage.

if i do it locally code runs fine but i dont see any data being stored.

if i upload the app to the app engine then i get a null pointer exception on running the code at:
AppEngineFile writableFile = fileService.createNewGSFile(optionsBuilder.build());

the complete code i m using is

```
        // Get the file service
        FileService fileService = FileServiceFactory.getFileService();

        /**
         * Set up properties of your new object
         * After finalizing objects, they are accessible
         * through Cloud Storage with the URL:
         * http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/my_bucket/my_object
         */
        GSFileOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder = new GSFileOptionsBuilder()
          .setBucket("blood")
          .setKey("1234567")
          .setAcl("public-read")
          .setMimeType("text/html");//.setUserMetadata("date-created", "092011", "owner", "Jon");


        // Create your object
        AppEngineFile writableFile = fileService.createNewGSFile(optionsBuilder.build());

        // Open a channel for writing
        boolean lockForWrite = true; // Do you want to exclusively lock this object?
        FileWriteChannel writeChannel = fileService.openWriteChannel(writableFile, lockForWrite);
        // For this example, we write to the object using the PrintWriter
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(Channels.newWriter(writeChannel, "UTF8"));
        out.println("The woods are lovely and deep.");
        out.println("But I have promises too keep.");

        // Close the object without finalizing.
        out.close();

        // Finalize the object
        writeChannel.closeFinally();
        System.out.println("Completed writing to google storage");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was that app engine was not authorized to read/write to the bucket created in the cloud store.

Answer (score 1):

When using the dev service and the file service with Google Storage, it does not actually write to your Google Storage bucket but to the local file system - are you expecting it to write to Google Storage?

For the null pointer exception would need to see a stack trace to try and narrow down what's going wrong.

Comment: You are talking about BlobStore "built-in" service. Google Cloud Storage is an external service to both dev environment and production (appspot.com)

Comment: Right Alex  you perfectly make sense. So any idea on the issue?

Comment: I know that - when using the files API on the app engine development server does not read or write to the external Google Storage service but mimics it reading and writing to the local disk.

Comment: so do u mean this is a known issue?

Comment: The dev appserver not writing to the actual Google Storage service is by design - not an issue.

Comment: hi as i said i m getting the exception at line AppEngineFile writableFile = fileService.createNewGSFile(optionsBuilder.build());

I do not see any stack trace getting printed all it throws is a java.io.exception

Comment: i have tried this even after removing the catch clause but i still get  no stack trace